# How to use the `colspan` in css3 inside the `row`

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make 2 columns, underneath one of the column need to have 3 rows. each rows has seperate number of cells. but it's not working for me. it should 100% wide, but it look like `inline-table` - how to fix this?

```css
#table {
    display:table;
    width:100%
}


.row {
    display:table-row;
}

.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid grey;
}

.row1 {
   display: table-caption;
}

.cell1 {
    width:30%
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell cell1">30%</div>
        <div class="cell cell2">
            
            <div class="row row1">
                <div class="cell"><h2>90%</h2></div>
                 <div class="cell"><h2>10%</h2></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row2">
                <div class="cell"><h2>40%</h2></div>
                <div class="cell"><h2>20%</h2></div>
                <div class="cell"><h2>20%</h2></div>
                <div class="cell"><h2>20%</h2></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row2">
                <div class="cell"><h2>100%</h2></div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Uh, it looks like you haven't set the width for any of the cells; try adding css width attributes.

Comment: else, all are correct? is this the way to create the table using css3? - but not working when applying the width

Comment: If you want a literal table (i.e. tabular data), you should use the table tag. But it looks like that's not what you're doing, and in general yeah, I think this is a workable way to build a grid system for your page layout. But you might find it easier to use a pre-built grid system like Bootstrap, Foundation, MaterializeCSS, Skeleton, etc etc etc (there's a big list of CSS frameworks if you scroll right on [this page](http://enboard.co/frontend/))

Comment: Can't i convert this above html as a valid table?

Comment: What do you mean, "a valid table"? I'm not sure if you're talking about a literal table (i.e. for displaying tabular data) or if you're talking about a page layout.

Comment: I would like to convert this html to table. because i can apply different width and height through css for different divices

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7qf3ay3s/